# Docker Python install fails to generate Egg Info due to "Operation not permitted"

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi3

I am running docker on my raspberry pi 3. I dockerize my Discord bots (running discord.py).

I use the following dockerfile to build my container

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:latest
USER root
ADD ./CrapBot/ /opt/BotPackage
WORKDIR /opt/BotPackage
RUN pip3 install .                <---- fails here
ENV TOKEN=******

ARG runtype
ENV runtype=$runtype
RUN echo $runtype

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/BotPackage/start.sh"]
```

This works fine on any other computer. I have a completely fresh install of docker on my RPI3. deleted all installs and configs everywhere I could find

My error is as follows specifically on the RPI3

```
#0 14.64 Processing /opt/BotPackage
#0 14.64   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#0 17.58   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#0 17.61   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 17.61
#0 17.61   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#0 17.61   │ exit code: 1
#0 17.61   ╰─> [3 lines of output]
#0 17.61       running egg_info
#0 17.61       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-c4sqlell/Crap_Bot.egg-info
#0 17.61       error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
#0 17.61       [end of output]
#0 17.61
#0 17.61   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 17.62 error: metadata-generation-failed
#0 17.62
#0 17.62 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#0 17.62 ╰─> See above for output.
#0 17.62
#0 17.62 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#0 17.62 hint: See above for details.
#0 18.25
#0 18.25 [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
#0 18.25 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

I get similar permission issues trying to update pip. I get GPG issues running `apt update` in the container. `docker run hello-world` seems to work as expected.

Extra context:
I have tried specifying user, changing perms ON the image of the folder (chown -R root:root /opt/...) (chmod 777 -R ...)
I have tried doing rpi-update. Rebooting several times. Changing permissions on the folder OUTSIDE of the container
I have also tried pre-generating egg-info with setup.py egginfo

I have also tried removing all of the install_requires from the setup.py just to see if something weird was happening. I am confident this is some OS permission issue with creating files in the docker tmp directory

I am really at wits end with this issue and I just cannot figure out what's going on.

Comment: "Operation not permitted" doesn't necessarily mean a problem with user permissions. The system may not permit the operation also because a lack of resources: disk space or RAM for example. Especially the build process is expensive... It would be better to build the image on your computer and only pull it from the RPI3

Comment: You might have a point with RAM being the issue. I do't see the pip install (and apt update, which gave me gpg key issues, another can of worms) being THAT expensive, as I haven't had issues building the same thing on a Pi4 2g in the past. maybe a pi3 is less optimized. I'll try to build and pull and see what happens